# Yii2 set form field value after form post gives error

Tags: post, yii2

I have quite a big form with multiple fields and multiple array fields.
As such I am not using the standard Yii2 rules but have rather developed my own function to validate the input.

I then get all fields upon submit using this code:

```
if (\Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
            $body = \Yii::$app->request->post();
```

This give me an array with all my fields as example.

```
Array
(
    [MyForm] => Array
        (
            [myName] => dfv
            [myNo] => dfv
            [myBookTitleId] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 1
                    [2] => 1
                    [3] => 1
                )
```

Then I validate the fields and set the error messages.

```
$myName = $body['MyForm']['myName'];    
if(trim($myName) != 'John') {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('grouperror', "Please complete your correct name.");
        return false;
    }
```

However when the page loads again, the flash error message is displayed but the myName field has lost the value I have entered and is now empty.

I have tried the following but none of them work:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'myName')->textInput(value' => $myName]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'myName')->textInput(value' => $model->$myName]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'myName')->textInput(value' => $model->myName]) ?>
```

How do I send the value back and set the myName field?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, but I had a few problems.

1. I had **$model = new BookForm()** every time I load my page. I removed this.
2. I changed **$myName = $body['MyForm']['myName']** to **$this->myName = $body['MyForm']['myName']**
3. No need to set the field value. I used only this: **$form->field($model, 'myName')->textInput()**

Now it work as expected.